# How to restrict IAM user to access (list) particular roles and CF stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I have created multiple service roles and CF Stacks, using root account and I'm going to create one IAM user and I don't want to list all these roles and CF stacks. I want to show only some particular roles and CF Stacks.
Can you please let me know how I can do this? It will be great if you share a sample policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying only a subset of all your IAM Roles in the console is not possible. The only way to restrict the `iam:ListRoles` call is with the `PathPrefix` argument (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_identityandaccessmanagement.html). However, the IAM Console issues a `iam:ListRoles` request without specifying the `PathPrefix` argument. You can still use the AWS CLI to request only a subset of IAM roles like this:

```
aws iam list-roles --path-prefix "/somepath"
```

And you can allow a user to list IAM Roles that have a path that starts with `/somepath` like this:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Resources:
  User:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: IamAccess
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - 'iam:ListRoles'
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/somepath*"
```

As for listing only a subset of all your CloudFormation stacks, that is not possible. The `ListStacks` call does not allow you to filter down which stacks to list. See See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awscloudformation.html . Just add the following snippet to the code above to allow your user to list all CloudFormation stacks:

```
      - PolicyName: CloudFormationAccess
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - 'cloudformation:ListStacks'
            Resource: '*'
```

Note that listing CloudFormation stacks does not implicitly give access to listing the Resources or Outputs of these stacks. In other words, the user may list all Stacks, but will not be able to look at the contents of these stacks.

Comment: **The user may list all Stacks, but will not be able to look at the contents of these stacks:**

I am allowing all permissions for the Cloud formation service to the new IAM user which I am going to create. Is there any way to hide or deny permissions on that particular stack (previously created by root user)?

Comment: To clarify: IAM Permissions determine whether or not a user is allowed to make an API call, with the given parameters. It does _not_ limit what data is returned. So, if a user only has permission to list Resource A, and they issue a request to list Resource A, it will work. If, instead, they try to list all resources, it will fail. It gives an allowed/disallowed, not a filter on results.